# Orthonormal basis of a Euclidean Space

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Given a Euclidean space $ R$, let $\psi_1, \psi_2,...,\psi_k,...$ be an orthonormal basis in $R$ and $f$ an arbitrary element of $R$. Prove that the element

$$f- \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \psi_{k} $$

is orthogonal to all linear combinations of the form
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{k} \psi_{k} $$

if and only if $\hspace{0.5cm}$ $a_k = (f,\psi_k) $  $\hspace{1cm}$ $(k=1,2,...,n)$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I've tried assuming that $a_k$ is defined as in the question, then trying to prove orthogonality between the 2 sums. However, I am quite lost with this problem.

Comment: If you use the given formula for $a_k$, can you prove using dot/inner products that the element in the first displayed equation is orthogonal to $\psi_1$? What about $\psi_2$? Hint: $\psi_i \cdot \psi_1 = 0$ unless $i = 1$, in which case it's $1$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the bilinearity of the scalar product, you can write

$$\left(f- \sum_{i=1}^na_i \psi_i, \sum_{j=1}^n b_j\psi_j \right) = \left(f, \sum_{j=1}^n b_j\psi_j \right) -\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i \psi_i, \sum_{j=1}^n b_j\psi_j \right) $$

$$ = \sum_{j=1}^nb_j (f,\psi_j) - \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^na_ib_j(\psi_i,\psi_j). $$

Since $\{\psi_i\}$ is an orthonormal set, $(\psi_i,\psi_j) =1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise, therefore

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^na_ib_j(\psi_i,\psi_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j$$

and we obtain

$$\left(f- \sum_{i=1}^na_i \psi_i, \sum_{j=1}^n b_j\psi_j \right) = \sum_{j=1}^nb_j (f,\psi_j)- \sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j = \sum_{j=1}^nb_j\left[(f,\psi_j)-a_j \right].$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: I was about to write a similar answer, however my computer decided it was time to update --' +1 for making my computer update so you could post this ;) (also for the nice answer off course)

Comment: Just to make sure I'm following, this part of the proof is relevant to proving both directions of the "if and only if". You have changed the first sum into a different form that is better to work with. Now I use the sum you have reached at the end, and use this to prove both directions of the proof. Is this correct? @stefano

Comment: @ReginaldDick Yes.

Comment: Okay. So If we assume that $a_k $ is as described in the question, then the term in the square brackets is zero, and then everything is orthogonal as desired. If not, then the sum is not zero, so we do not have orthogonality. Is that it?

Comment: The first part (the _if_ ) is correct. The second not quite. The key for the _only if_ part is that the sum we have obtained is zero **for all** choices of $b_k$. Can you use this to deduce that $a_k$ has the desired form?

Comment: We need the sum to equal zero for any choice of $b_j$. This can only happen if the scalar product minus $a_j$ equals 0 always. So that scalar product must be defined in the way we want!?

Comment: Intuitively, yes. Formally, in order to make a $(f,\psi_k)-a_k = 0$ for a fixed $k$, you can simply choose $b_j=1$ if $j=k$ and $b_j=0$ otherwise.